# Tried to get facebook event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/895895040502397/events/attending/?fields=id,name,description,place,timezone,start_time,cover&offset=0&limit=2000&access_token=xxxxxxx&since=&until=2997993600
```

With this url I am getting below error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (fql) on node type (User)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100
      }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix it.

Comment: you really should not post access tokens...they should always be kept serect.

Comment: You should at least quote error messages correctly …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.../895895040502397/attending...
```

Remove "events", the ID is already the ID of a specific event.

Answer (score 1):

You can get event like this.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/895895040502397/attending/.....
```

Also Use CURL PHP.